# Which word should I use, "master" or "Master"

Tags: nouns, case

When I am writing a personal statement, I am confused by the word "master". I don't know weather I can use the lower case because that's showed in the dictionary. But my friend from the UK told me that I should use "Master".
So, which one is correct?

1. My short-term goal is to specialize in data science through this master's programme.
2. My short-term goal is to specialize in data science through this Master's programme.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a small 'm'. We usually do not capitalise (capitalize in US) the degree level when writing generally. Capitalise when talking about a particular degree or course. In academic writing, you should consult an appropriate style guide. The quotation below shows a widespread convention:

> In general, academic degrees are capitalized only when the full name
>   of the degree is used, such as Bachelor of Arts or Master of Social
>   Work. General references, such as bachelor’s, master’s or doctoral
>   degree, are not capitalized.

[Writing Style Guide (Western Michigan University)](https://wmich.edu/writing/rules/capitalization)